# How can I fix My Windows Key and Alt Key?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't exactly remember the time till when my <kbd>Windows</kbd> key was functional, but if I can give an estimate, it must have been till the day when my computer nearly missed an attack by a ransomware (Ransom:MSIL/JigsawLocker.A) while trying to download some (fake, I think) version of Bandicam from a user named `unpack98` on GitHub. My younger brother aided me in fending the malware off from taking over my computer that time. Then we downloaded an original version of Bandicam from their own website. Since then, my <kbd>Windows</kbd> key seemed to be unresponsive.We tried various fixes (mainly Command Prompt tools) but in vain. I hunted for the Scancode Map entry in the Registry but again in vain. We updated this system to the new Windows 10 Pro 20H2 version, hoping to have the issue fixed, but nothing came of it. And today (I noticed it today) my <kbd>alt</kbd> key isn't working (except the <kbd>alt</kbd> + [<kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>8</kbd>] shortcut, which seemed to work on MS Teams). I tried to put a smiley using <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> but it didn't work - that's how I noticed it. My brother ran the `sfc /scannow` command and the `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` command and nothing worked...
I would like to know if I require a hardware fix or if there's any shortcut method to fix it. My PC isn't a desktop PC but a laptop (if there's any specificity in the methods to be used).

> Note : I don't have the <kbd>WinLock</kbd> key

Comment: Have you tried with a different good (USB) keyboard? The two events might not be related.

Comment: @User552853 no, I haven't...

Comment: @User552853 is it actually a software conflict?

Comment: My computer uses that Standard PS/2 Keyboard drivers.

Comment: @User552853 my Shift + R has gone off now !

Comment: The other Shift key combos are working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if the touch keyboard is working. Press the Windows key + R to open the Run box. Type 'tabtip' and press Enter.
2. Try running window in safe mode.Hold the Shift Key down while you select Power > Restart. After your PC restarts to the Choose an Option screen, select Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Startup Settings > Restart. After your PC restarts, a list of options should appear. Select 4 or F4 to start your PC in Safe Mode.
3. Try on a different os (you don't need to install a new os, you can live boot from a USB)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this problem now I'd recommend **downloading** [SharpKeys](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/sharpkeys/XPFFCG7M673D4F) off of the microsoft store  to **rebind the keys that may have gotten messed with**. You can also use a website like [KeyboardChecker](https://keyboardchecker.com) *or* [What Key Am I Pressing](http://whatkeyamipressing.com) in order to ***see if the button is still functional at all*** and just got rebound weirdly in the registry, likely after an update or restore or whatever. Hope this helps :) -*Bauldi*